# Addressing several columns in a ListObject for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting, listobject

I'm working with a table (Excel 365) which contains 50 columns and about 7000 rows (increasing). The table is formatted as ListObject. So far so good.
Now I need to address 8 columns - not next to each other and all at once - to assign 4 different conditional formats to them. Procedure

```
Set condition = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=.....")
```

Obviousely it is not possible to create another array out of the ListObject (Message: types incompatible). At least I couldn't find a way yet. I also tried

```
With rng 
    .FormatConditions.Add
```

..... but VBA always asks for a "=".

Anybody any ideas? Is it possible at all?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is to set `rng` to the correct Range before applying the FormatConditions. The columns of a table are accessible with `ListColumns`. This is a collection of all columns of a table. Therefore you can address a single column either via index or via column name (the name of a column is defined by the header cell).

The range of a column can be accessed by the property `Range`. However, that includes the header row, and usually you don't want to apply the formatting to the header. Instead, you can use the property `DataBodyRange`, this omits the header cell.

To get all cells of all columns of interest, simply use the `Union`-command.

So your code could look like this:

```
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)  ' Change to your needs
Dim rng As Range

' Define the list of columns you want to use.     
Dim colList, i As Long
colList = Array(2, 3, 5)                     ' Either by index...
colList = Array("Name", "Street", "Info") ' ... or by name

' Loop over the columns and build the Range
For i = LBound(colList) To UBound(colList)
    Dim col As ListColumn
    Set col = table.ListColumns(colList(i))
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rng = col.DataBodyRange
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, col.DataBodyRange)
    End If
Next

' Optional: Remove existing FormatConditions  
Do While table.DataBodyRange.FormatConditions.Count > 0
    table.DataBodyRange.FormatConditions(1).Delete
Loop

' Now set new FormatConditions for the Range
Dim fc As FormatCondition
Set fc = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False) & ">5")
fc.Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Note that once you have applied the conditional formatting to the table columns, it will "grow" when you add new rows - with other words the new rows will have the same formatting automatically.

Comment: Yes, you're right, forgot to copy the definition for `rng` from my test code - updated the answer. But then it should do, cannot explain why you get the error.

Comment: Perfect!!!! You saved my project :-) Many thanks!

Comment: That was my fault - had a mistake in the code